# How can i move resources between resource groups in different subscriptions in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

I am trying to move resources between subscriptions. I try to move and select "show hidden types" but I get the error with 2 resources
The resources are

canadacentral-Canada Centralwebspace-221016172710 the type is
microsoft.web/certificates
The error i get when trying to move my resources is :

This resource is located in resource group 'CanadaCentralResourceGroup',
but hosted in the resource group 'canadacentral'.
This may be a result of prior move operations.
Move it back to respective hosting resource group

If i look at the Resourcegroup canadacentral there are no resources
Why isnt it allowing me to move the resources ?

Comment: Have you tried Stopping your resource from running? After Stopping it then you need to move it.

Comment: Is the resource free App Service managed certificate?

Comment: No the app service has a healthy certificate , expires next year .

Comment: It is a live system , what do i stop the actual app services ? there are 2 app services in the resource group

Comment: I cant see these webspace in Azure , but if i look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/91427/are-the-certificates-uploaded-to-a-web-app-or-func.html I can , but how does that help ?

Comment: It says that it is in the correct resourcegroup

Comment: These webspaces are actually hidden types  does that matter or does admin have access to viewing those ?

Comment: You Cannot move a certificate on its own even if it is not binded

Comment: Ok so i dont select the certificate and once they are moved do i rebind ? Because i did it to a different resourcegroup and it worked fine

Comment: Yes, you can upload that certificate into new subscription and then rebind it.

Comment: Ok so if i dont select the certificate , now it gives issue with App Service Plans. It says to move everything back to the hosting resource group, but the hosting resourcegroup is now CanadaCentralResourceGroup not canadacentral. Cant i detach from canadacentral some how , i mean it doesnt have any resources at all

Comment: Its actually saying that error for all the resources, I need to move them back to the hosting resourcegroup and then move. But how can i move to a different resourcegroup on the same subscription , doesnt allw you to unless you move each individual resource ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250339/discussion-between-rithwikbojja-and-veronica).

Answer (score 0):

You can move resources using PowerShell Command as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#move-1):

```
 webapp=$(az resource show -g OldRG -n ExampleSite --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/sites" --query id --output tsv)
    plan=$(az resource show -g OldRG -n ExamplePlan --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms" --query id --output tsv)
    az resource move --destination-group newgroup --ids $webapp $plan
```

**Note:** You cannot move a certificate on its own even if it is not binded and also if it is resource free App Service managed certificate.

**To move to different resource group:**

Firstly, click on a particular resource then you will be having move option on resource group as below:

[image]

**References taken from:**

- http://terenceluk.blogspot.com/2021/04/moving-app-service-resources-from-one.html  by @Terence Luk